# Word with transcription [jərn] or [jən]

Tags: pronunciation, vocabulary

In English, is there any word that has the following transcription:

- [jən] or
- [jə:rn]

Many thanks!

Comment: [jə:rn] or [je:rn]?

Comment: I can't think how /ə:/ would be pronounced. I suspect that the second should actually be [jɜ:ʳn], which is the word *yearn*. The first usually appears as part of words like *companion;* I'm not sure it appears on its own. Perhaps others know. You certainly can't use /ə/ for simply **any** "e" sound. Yen, for example, is [jen], not [jən].

Comment: [Yearn -> /jə:rn/](https://contemporary_en.enacademic.com/43189). It's weird.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Yearn is the word that matches the second one, it's what I'm looking for. Why it's weird?

Comment: What if [jən] occurs word-medially? [Example: companionable -> /kəmˈpæn.jən.ə.bəl/](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/companionable).

Comment: @petwho Could you please explain your reason for asking the question? Have you heard the two words? If so where and in what context?

Comment: The Scotsman at the circus (old joke) said "I cannot open my mouth as wide as yon lion did".

Comment: @Greybeard long story short. I found that, via Oxford, Cambridge, Longman, etc., the pronunciation for "impudent" /ˈɪmpjədənt/ sounds more like /ˈɪmpɪdənt/ or /ˈɪmpi:dənt/. Then I try to find a word that has /jə/ to find some clues to support my assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In English, is there any word that has the following transcription:
>
> [jən] or [jə:rn]

The problem here is that "in English" covers a great deal of ground. The word "yearn" sounds different in US and UK English, not to mention New Zealand and other places.

The [jən] version is most likely intended to be from southern England because of the non-rhotic "r".

However in English we have not only to contend with long and short vowels (yearn has a long vowel) but a pitch change in the the middle of vowels. In my version of English this would show up as something like [jə:ən] where the first ə is higher pitched than the second.

I can't think of anywhere they would say [jən].

P.S. I hope someone will correct my IPA if necessary.

Comment: *The [jən] version is most likely from southern England because of the non-rhotic "r"* — The pronounciation of 'yearn' in Southern England is [je:n], not [jən].

Comment: @Decapitated Soul - Thanks, in fact I've just edited slightly to [jə:ən] to indicate the pitch change. I said in my existing answer that  no-one uses  [jən]